# How to use multiple JSON objects for single NodeJS/Jade Merge

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

Given the following setup code (loosely realistic)

default.js (used by config.js for loading base configurations)

```
{
  "templateData": {
    "corp": {
        "corpName": "Company",
        "DepartmentOne": {
            "name": "DepartmentOne",
            "phone": "1-800-555-555",
            "email": "departmentone@company.com"
        },
        "address": {
            "main": {
                "addressLine1": "Somwhere",
                "city": "SomeTown",
                "stateShort": "SState",
                "stateLong": "SomeState",
                "zipCodeShort": "Zippy"
            }
        },
        "urls": {
            "company": {
                "corporate": {
                    "site": "https://company.com/",
                    "logo": "http://sites.company.com/images/logo.png",
                    "altText" : "Company Corporate Logo"
                },
                "facebook": {
                    "site": "https://www.facebook.com/company",
                    "icon": "http://sites.company.com/images/facebook.png",
                    "altText" : "Company Facebook Page"
                },
                "twitter": {
                    "site": "https://twitter.com/company",
                    "icon": "http://sites.company.com/images/twitter.png",
                    "altText" : "Company Twitter Feed"
                },
                "youtube": {
                    "site": "https://www.youtube.com/company",
                    "icon": "http://sites.company.com/images/youtube.png",
                    "altText" : "Company YouTube Channel"
                }
            }
        },
        "currentYear": "2015",
        "corpWebSiteName": "Company.com"
    }
  }
}
```

test01.js (main node code)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
var jade = require('jade');
var config = require('config');
var restify = require('restify');


var log = bunyan.createLogger({src: false, name: "emailTemplateMerger"});

var html = '';

var corpConfig = config.get('templateData');

var emailData = { 'emailAddress' : 'nonya@bidness.com',
              'firstName' : 'nonya',
              'lastName' : 'bidness'
            }

var miscData = { 'billingDate' : '2015-08-01',
             'accountType' : 'new',
             'discountTypes' : {
               'primary' : 'Coupon20',
               'bonus' : 'First30Days',
               'standard' : 'freeShipping'
            }
          }


fs.readFile('./emailTemplates/test01.jade', 'utf-8', function(error, source){
  var template = jade.compile(source);

  html = template(corpConfig)

   console.log(html);
});
```

Jade Template:

```
html
  head
  body
    p.
      Hello #{emailData.firstName},
    p.
     Welcome to #{corp.corpName}'s #{DepartmentOne.name}.
    p. 
      Your next bill will be sent on #{miscData.billingDate} for your #{miscData.accountType}.
    p.
       Thank you
```

Problem: Determining an efficient method of merging the config data and the 2 local datasets (which will be passed in via REST) into the Jade template.

Since the data has many levels of nesting, a direct merge can be complex and possibly error prone depending on the data passed in, is there anyway to pass Jade multiple, separate datasets and defer the merging to the Jade engine?

I've tried multiple passes, but a single pass of the Jade merge removes all tags from the template so that didn't work out. I haven't figured out anyway to chain the results.

Comment: The example code above ignores the local data objects miscData and emailData.

Comment: There are libraries out there (Lodash) that perform efficient deep clone/merge

Comment: I tried the Lodash library and merge works great for this project. However, I went with Ryan's answer below since it was the simplest approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a top level context object like this:

```
var context = {
    corp: corpConfig,
    email: emailData,
    misc: miscData
};

....

var html = template(context);
```

And then change the template references to something like this

```
html
  head
  body
    p.
      Hello #{context.email.firstName},
    p.
      Welcome to #{context.corp.corpName}'s #{context.misc.DepartmentOne.name}.
```

Comment: That's so obvious, I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't think of it. For the specific case that I'm needing, that works perfectly.